# Move all database tables under another database with new Schema?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

So I've been tasked with researching something I've never done before.

3 Application modules built using C# in VS2010 are using 1 database (Database1) with the tables such as **dbo.Samples**, which all have the schema "dbo.*Table*". For some higher-up unknown reason, it has been requested that all these tables under Database1 be moved into Database2 which has many more schemas such as padmin.PSTIF, petro.Facilities, webdc.AppTransactions, etc.

In these 3 modules all connection strings are configured through the **app.config** file, and all data transactions/selections for display are done through hard-coded SQL statements using the connectionstrings.

My concern is, if I move **dbo.Samples** from Database1 and into Database2 with a schema change to something such as **moss.Samples**, will each of those hard-coded statements need updated as well? Current I can just code something like "SELECT * FROM Samples". Will I have to change this statement since it will be using a new schema, even if I update the connection string to Database2?

**EDIT:**

I added some dummy copy tables of DB1 to the Test Environment version of DB2 and experimented in the application. After changing the connection string to now point to DB2, I found I have to go through each hard-coded SQL statement and change each use of a table to include the new schema (change `FROM Sample` to `FROM moss.Sample`).

Does anyone know if it is possible to specify the schema I wish to use in the connection string itself? This would save me from changing roughly 200 individual statements across 3 applications if possible.

My example connection string is below:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="conString" connectionString="Data Source=SERVER.domain.state.acroynym.us;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=true;"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

I tried changing `Initial Catalog=DatabaseName` to `Initial Catalog=DatabaseName.moss`, but the application returned that it could not find the database `DatabaseName.moss`, which makes sense, just figured it was worth a try.

Comment: Related - please read both to understand why you should never use `SELECT * FROM Samples` : https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list.aspx https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2009/10/11/bad-habits-to-kick-avoiding-the-schema-prefix.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the articles Aaron, but just to clarify I used the `SELECT * FROM Samples` as an example. My true statements are returning only the necessary columns.

Comment: The schema prefix article still applies: don't try to find some hack so you can be lazy about not specifying the schema. This is more important than ease of a one-time migration.

Comment: After perusing the article I understand the importance. I'm still curious though if it would be possible to modify the connection string to somehow point to my desired schema, keeping me from needing to change 200ish hard-coded SQL statements across 3 applications to have the new schema with the table names.

Comment: Should be Initial Catalog = 'moss.Sample'. DatabaseName is a variable in that case. You could also try Initial Catalog = 'Moss.' + DatabaseName. Or find out where databaseName is set and change it there (BTW these are ugly hacks that I am giving you)

Comment: @AnalyticLunatic no, the connection string has no way to tell your application to use `moss` instead of `dbo`. And while you could change the default schema for the application user (assuming it's SQL auth) or all of the Windows users, **this is not a good thing.**

Comment: @orgtigger not sure what you're getting at - the Initial Catalog expects a database, not `schema.database` or whatever it is you're implying there

Answer (score 1):

Hi Analytic Lunatic,

There may some additional steps that you need to take on the database side as well. Merely copying a database does not copy all of its additional information. Triggers, Constraints, indexes and Permissions are not automatically copied into the new database. You might be better off using the copy wizard.

Comment: Oh I'm sure there is! I've never done database migration myself. I've merely been asked to look into this due to being the only remaining original developer of the applications using DB1 left in our group.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many implicit issues, potential problems and unknowns in your question...  Just a few points:

1) Yes, you can easily move data from one table to another, or two a completely different database, in many different ways.  Including [SSIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/cc511477.aspx)  and ["select into"](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp).

2) No, you seldom ever want to do a "select *" in production code.

3) Yes, any hard-coded statement that accesses one column in one table will probably have to be modified to access a different column in a different table :)

Comment: Just to clarify, I used the `SELECT * FROM Samples` as an example. My true statements are returning only the necessary columns. So on point 3, if I move everything into DB2, instead of saying `FROM Samples` and the application implicitly knowing I mean `dbo.Samples` from DB1 in the connection string, I would have to do `FROM moss.Samples` even with the connection string newly pointing to DB2? In DB1 all schemas are `dbo` whereas in the new DB2 there are already several different schemas as listed.

Comment: Ah, so your question is really about "fully qualified names".  SUGGESTIONS: 1) Don't get too hung up on "connection strings": there are lots of other issues/alternatives to consider, 2) Check out some of these links: [Fully Qualified Table Names & Synonyms](http://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/20337/fully-qualified-table-name.html), [SQL Server Set Default Schema](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4942023/set-default-schema-for-a-sql-query), or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4273242/hundreds-of-aliases-synonyms-vs-database-tables-fully-qualified-names.  'Hope that helps...

Comment: Thanks for the articles. I've edited my post with where I now stand on the issue.